# Dynamic Range with Calculation

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

I would like to make my range dynamic, while still including formulas. Any ideas? It needs to find the last row, and include the calculation on all rows for the two columns.

```
 Sheets("Opérations").Activate
 Range("AS3").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],Time!R1C1:R16C2,2,TRUE)"
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS3:AS8655")

 Range("AS3:AS8655").Select
 Range("AT3").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(Time!R[-2]C[-35]<>Maturities!R3C17,VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Time!R1C4:R2585C5,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Time!R1C7:R2585C8,2,FALSE))"

 Range("AT3").Select
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AT3:AT8655")
 Range("AT3:AT8655").Select
```

Comment: Create a dynamic named range using offset in the sheet and then refer to that Range(“namedrange”).Formula = or a variation on that theme .FormulaR1C1......  excuse the funny “ due to mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to put the formula dynamically till the last row:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateRangeWithFormulaString()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim VlookupRng As Range
Dim FormulaStr As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCell As Range

' set the Vlookup Range
Set VlookupRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time").Range("A1:B16")

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Op")

With Sht
    FormulaStr = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Range("AS3").Offset(, -6).Address(False, False, xlA1) & "," & VlookupRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal) & ",2,TRUE)"

    Debug.Print FormulaStr ' <-- helps to debug the Formula String

    ' Using Find to find the last row in a worksheet

    Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LastCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Error! worksheet is empty", vbCritical
        End
    End If

    ' populate the entire range with the formula
    .Range("AS3:AS" & LastRow).Formula = FormulaStr
End With

End Sub
```